# How to search a large Outlook/PST database for email by hour of the day or between hours of the day

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010, search, export, time

I have a 13 giga big PST file and i need to export all emails from specific hour of day / range of hour of day.

If i succeed to search all emails that has , for example, 19:30, in received time field i can manage to export them.

But i don't even go to that point. I have tried a lot of Addins but none of them can sort/find emails by specific hour of day.

Export to CSV dont export the Date field.

May msaccess but i am not comfortable with it.

It's seems very tricky

By any mean nescesay :) (i can use unix tools against and CSV or whatever).

(i use french date format (but dont care) )

Comment: Is your outlook connected to an exchange server on premise or office 365 that you have access to? Or are you just using outlook as a mail client for a personal mail account?

Comment: I'm connected to a O365 corporate account but i also have all the emails exported in a PST file.

Comment: even creating a custom "hour" field with formula or changing the Received column format to show only the hour doesnt helps because after that you cannot sort it (received column act like before and the custom field with formula cannot be searched/sorted)

Comment: It seems like outlook spefically prevent you from doing by hour search....

Comment: the only way i have found for now would be to use this addins https://www.encryptomatic.com/messageexport/ to export each email in separate PDF file and using the Naming Scheme functionnality to put HH:MM:SS at the begining of each file...but it's not free (80$)..thats insane...

Comment: Actually, just tested this `received:4/15/2016 04:08:00 PM..4/15/2016 04:15:00 PM` in search bar. It singled out one email from 4:10:00 pm.

Comment: Yes but i would need something like:  "*/*/* 06:00:00 PM..*/*/* 10:00:00 PM"

Comment: in other words, every mail from anytime received between 06:00:00 PM and 10:00:00 PM

Comment: Do you need to export all message data or just some of fields (like subject, date, ...)?